# Add an js file depending on the action. Zend

Tags: javascript, php, zend-framework

I'm using zend framework to create a web project and I was wondering if there is a way to insert in the template or view a javascript file depending on the type of action. For instance if I had this action:

```
 public function indexAction() {
        $this->_helper->layout->setLayout("layout_ember");
        //$this->headScript()->appendFile('/scripts/menu.js'); //no work
    }
```

I want to add the file menu.js to the view/template.

Can you help me with this?

I'm using Zend Framework Version: 1.12.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

In your action :

to add js at the bottom of view

```
$this->view->InlineScript()->appendFile($this->view->baseUrl() .'/scripts/menu.js');
```

to add js in the header

```
$this->view->headScript()->appendFile($this->view->baseUrl() .'/scripts/menu.js'); //
```

In your Layout
For js in head :

```
<head>
<?php
    echo $this->headScript() ;
?>
 </head>
```

For js at the bottom :

```
<?php
    echo $this->InlineScript(); 
?>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
$this->view->headScript()->appendFile('/path/to/file.js');
```